# Help understanding multidimensional array and pointer notation in c++

Tags: c++

I understand the basic idea that when an array is the sole operand of the & or sizeof() operator, it decays to a pointer to the first element in the array.  I'm unsure how these notations work though.  In our text, there is the 1-D case, vs the 3-D case for an array.  The first example is the function declaration for a function called average.  The 1-D case is

```
double average(double set[]) or
double average(double *set)
```

Those make sense to me.  The equivalent multi-D case does not.  Their declaration is

```
double average (double set[][DIM1][DIM2]) or
double average (double (*set)[DIM1][DIM2])
```

Similarly, the function declaration for printing a value for 1-D is:

```
double *printvalue(double value)
```

The multi-D case is:

double (*printvalue(double value))[DIM1][DIM2]

Can anyone shed any light on this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter still decays to a pointer.  The important part is that DIM1 and DIM2 specify the size of all but one dimension.  So, if we have:

```
double average (double set[][DIM1][DIM2] myset)
```

myset[0][0] is DIM2 * sizeof(double) before myset[0][1].  Together, the two dimensions say that myset[0] is DIM1 * DIM2 * sizeof(double) before myset[1].  You don't need a DIM0 on the left, because the number of rows doesn't affect the pointer arithmetic.  You can always leave out the leftmost dimension for this reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can still obtain value of pointer to chosen node of the array. The difference if whether you get the address alone (value, taken from the compiler), or value of a real pointer (a variable residing somewhere in memory). This also implies memory layout.

In case of an array with empty `[]` braces and initializer the pointer itself won't exist, just its value: For `char a[] = {1,2};` the value of `a` will be the memory location of `a[0]`, equivalent to `&a[0]`. But you can't get `char** b = &a`, location of the pointer, as you could with `char* a = {1,2}`.

Also, pure array guarantees continuity of memory. You can call any element like this:

```
 int values[MAX_Y][MAX_X];
```

or like this:

```
 int values_flat[MAX_Y*MAX_X]; 
 #define values(x,y) = (*( values_flat + MAX_X * (y) + (x) ))
```

These are equivalent internally. One continuous block of memory with its structure being an arbitrary choice of the compiler.

Not so with

```
 int* values[MAX_VAL];
```

This is really MAX_VAL pointers to arbitrary locations in memory. `values[0][MAX_VAL]` in case of `array[][]` would equal `values[1][0]`. In case of array of pointers, it could point to an arbitrary memory location outside of allocated space.

Comment: Even though C guarantees contiguity in the "array or array" case, `values[0][MAX_VAL]` is undefined because you're using an out-of-bounds index.  It is true that `values[0] + MAX_VAL == values[1]`, though :-).  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036104 for a discussion.