# About two dimensional arrays in C--> Is array[1][0] and array[0][1] the same?

Tags: c, arrays

```
int main ()
{
    int arr[10][1];
    arr[1][0]=44;
    arr[0][1]=55;
    printf("%i",arr[1][0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Should this print out "55" or "44"???

Comment: This should cause nasal demons.

Comment: This is not a HOMEWORK Mr. Strohm.. I thought i knew about C arrays but that simple code printed out a result i did not expect (which is 55 in that case). So i am looking for an explanation..

Comment: **[UB](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?UndefinedBehavior)** FTW

Comment: If you knew about C arrays, where did you expect that 55 to be stored?

Answer (score 4):

There is no such element as `arr[0][1]` -- just as there is no element `arr[10][0]` -- array indices are zero based.

If you declare:

```
int arr[10][2];
```

Your code will work as you intended.

With the declaration

```
int arr[10][1];
```

when you access `arr[0][1]` you are accessing beyond the end of the first array "row."  Memory access in C is not checked, so your access aliases the element stored at `arr[1][0]`.

If you swapped the order of the two assignment statements, you would see that the value displayed depends on the order of those two assignments.  The later assignment writes over the value from the earlier assignment. I.e.:

```
int main ()
{
    int arr[10][1];
    arr[0][1]=55;
    arr[1][0]=44;
    printf("%i",arr[1][0]);
    return 0;
}
```

...would print 44, simply because that would be the final value written to that int-sized spot in memory.

EDIT: Because we have so many people commenting here, claiming to interpret the lousy C99 standard as declaring the behavior you have invoked as "undefined behavior"...  Consider that the following code does the same thing as above, due to section 6.5.2.1:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int arr[10][1];

    arr[1][0] = 44;
    arr[0][1] = 55;

    printf("Value is: %d\n", 0[arr][1]);

    return 0;
}
```

In a linked question, the claim has been made that the C compiler may choose to pad the space between array "rows" due to alignment concerns.  That is disinformation; no C standard says that is possible.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing out the obvious. I know that if i declare it as [10][2] there will be no problem. but why does the program assign 55 to arr[1][0] is beyond me...

Comment: Ok. After a little thinking i can understand it now. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I'm sorry you thought that was "obvious" -- you didn't make it clear in your question that you knew this.  I guess the step you're missing is that all the array elements are stored contiguously in memory, so that arr[1][0] is immediately after arr[0][0] and writing arr[0][1] means the same things as "the int immediately after arr[0][1]".  I'm not sure how to help you more -- this stuff about pointers, aliasing and arrays is sort of the basics of C.  Maybe go back and read the original K&R?  It's actually really good.

Comment: No the step i am missing is the 8 hours sleep i should have had. I'm sorry if i offended you in anyway. Thank you again for the answer.

Comment: @Ancc -- Missing a night's sleep can disturb your personality for 60 days.  Don't do it.  Anyway, no offense taken.  I was mostly frustrated I couldn't get the answer to you.

Comment: @Heath Your claim about sleep and personality is of personal interest to me. Do you have a citation or link where I could follow up on it? Thanks.

Comment: @Alok you talk about "array indexing" but there's no such thing in C, there's only pointer arithmetic and dereferencing: `a[i]` is defined to be equivalent to `*(a + i)`. The standard refers to access within an "array object" -- only one of which is declared in an array declaration such as `arr[10][1]`.

Comment: `arr` is an array, but `arr[0]` through `arr[9]` are 10 arrays of one element each.  `arr[0]` in particular, is a one-element array, so you can't do `arr[0][1]` any more than you can do `int a[1]; a[1] = 42;`.  The fact that `arr[1][0]` occupies the same memory as `arr[0][1]` doesn't matter to the standard: `arr[0][1]` is UB.

Comment: @Alok - Please quote the relevant standard section, I dare you.  What you have written pertains to C#, not C.

Comment: @Alok - I see what you've written below relating to 6.5.2.1 and 6.5.6.  U R reading it wrong.  arr[0][1] == *(arr + (1 * 0) + 1) == *(arr + 1).  arr[1][0] == *(arr + (1 * 1) + 0) == *(arr + 1).  C is not an interpreted language with references, it's a memory-mapped  language with pointers.  Learn how it works and how it is defined.

Comment: @Heath `arr[0][1] == *(arr + (1 * 0) + 1)` -- No, it isn't. The translation for array subscripting is clearly given and requires one deference for each subscript: `*(*(arr + 0) + 1)`. "Learn how it works" -- Learn how not to be arrogant.

Comment: @Jim -- I left off a leading star.  Having also read paragraphs 3 and 4 of 6.5.2.1, and realizing that *arr == (int *)arr;, I don't think the difference in writing the expression is meaningful -- other than having left off a dereference star in front.

Comment: @Jim -- Ok, having seen where you are going with the point you made, let me ask you this:  According to the C standard's terminology for the word "object," is arr an object?  Is arr[1] also an object?

Comment: Is the following code legal according to the standards for C and the C standard library (use ANSI):  int arr[10][2]; memset(arr, 0, sizeof(arr));  (?)

Answer (score 1):

No they are not the same. You declared an array of ten arrays each with a single integer element. `arr[0][1]` is greater than your array index so should be an error. The result should be 44.

Comment: Yet the result comes out as 55. Why would that be?

Comment: @Anc - Because `arr[0][1]` is illegal. You've declared your array as `int arr[10][1]`, which means it has 10 columns and 1 row. Then `arr[0][1]` tries to access the second row of the first column, which doesn't exist, so it does crazy things.

Comment: @Chris -- It's not illegal.  It just isn't what OP expected.

Comment: @Heath - I'm 99% sure this isn't defined behavior in the C standard. Hence, illegal.

Comment: @Anc: because you invoked undefined behavior.

Comment: @Chris Lutz: undefined means undefined; the compiler is under no requirement to reject the code or cause an error to be signaled in the binary.  *Any* result is possible, and as far as the standard is concerned, equally correct.

Comment: @Chris, @John -- Show me where any C standard indicates this behavior is undefined.  In fact, ISO 9899:TC2, Section 6.5.2.1 defines how this will behave.  I understand that any access beyond the storage defined for the array would surely invoke undefined behavior.  But I believe what you are saying about array indices, pointer access, etc., is simply not correct.  The access in question is within the defined space, just accessed in an odd way.

Comment: -1 For an array declared as arr[X][0], arr[0][1] is colocated with arr[1][0], so the result, according to the language standard, must be 55. Of course, that's not likely what the programmer wants or expects, but the solution to that is to keep indices within bounds.

Comment: Oops, I meant declared as `declared as arr[X][1]` -- darn that 5 minute edit limit.

Comment: @Jim and @Heath, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036104/validity-of-the-code/2036206#2036206 for a more detailed discussion.  The part about "The result should be 44" is wrong, though. :-)

Comment: @Alok I believe that your answer there is incorrect -- there is only one "array object" here, and that is `arr`.

Comment: @Jim I think I am right.  It's a theoretical discussion mostly though, since "in practice", I agree with you.  But *technically* -- which is what we're discussing here -- I am not wrong.  https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.c/Nwh8dLFOhdI/--Tsv8t0PPgJ is another message in the same thread on comp.lang.c that I mention in my other answer.

Comment: @Alok I have explained why you are wrong: the standard language, which is quoted in the "validity-of-the-code" question, refers to an "array object", which here is `arr`, and all accesses are within that object, therefore there is no UB. I didn't make any statement about "in practice", so there is nothing for you to agree with me on in that regard.

Comment: @Jim, but then C doesn't have multi-dimensional arrays, so `arr[0]` through `arr[9]` are the only valid indexing for `arr` you can do.  In addition, you can `arr+10` is okay to calculate.  As soon as you start doing `arr[i][j]`, you are now talking about the array `arr[i]`, and not `arr`.

Comment: @Alok Section 6.5.2.1 of the standard says "Successive subscript operators designate an element of a multidimensional array object." And as I noted in response to your other comment, C doesn't have array indexing as such, it only has pointer arithmetic and dereferencing. Within the terms of the standard, there is no "array object" `arr[i]`, there is only the array object `arr`.

Comment: @Jim so what's the "object" of "pointer arithmetic" in `arr[0][1]`?  For `arr[0]`, `arr` is the object.  For the second indexing, you are indexing `arr[0]` by the index `1`.  `arr[0]` is a 1-element array, and the indexing is equivalent to `*(*(arr+0)+1)`.  Similarly, `arr[1][0]` is equivalent to `*(*(arr+1)+0)`.  Where in the standard does it say that `arr[0] + 1` is okay to be dereferenced?

Comment: @Alok Ok, I've studied the standard some more, and I concede that it no where specifies what the value of `arr[0][1]` is ... so one cannot assume that it is `arr[1][0]`. And the description of subscripting in 6.5.2.1 talks about converting an n-dimensional array into a pointer to an n-1 dimensional array, and section 6.5.6 specifies that pointer arithmetic results in UB if a pointer past an array is dereferenced, so I agree that your interpretation is correct. Now I know better!

Comment: @Jim - The idea that the "rows" of an array are "sub-arrays" is wrong.  The entire array is by-6.5.2.1 contiguous, and arr[0][1] is within the array, not past it.  Newbie programmers have gotten contaminated by C and Java.  In http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036104/validity-of-the-code Greg Hewgill tries to justify this interpretation by claiming the compiler can pad between the sub-arrays.  This would be LOL funny if it weren't that all this lack of understanding C is leading to people dumbing it down to the level of C#.

Comment: @Heath: I don't know why you keep bringing C# into this. C# has _nothing to do with it_.

Comment: @Tomalak -- Because people are describing two-dimensional arrays as being composed of arrays of arrays -- a concept they must have gotten from Java or C#.  I am saying that people who grew up in these new languages don't understand what the C definition is telling them, because they are applying wrong concepts.

Comment: @Heath: nowhere am I saying that the total space pointed to by `arr` is discontiguous.  There cannot be any padding between `arr[0]` and `arr[1]`.  And yes, it will be really hard to find a system where `arr[0][1]` wasn't the same as `arr[1][0]`.  BUT: the standard says that `arr[0][1]` is undefined while `arr[1][0]` is defined.  A bounds-checking compiler is allowed to not compile your code or give you a runtime error for `arr[0][1]`.  (I don't know Java or C#, FYI.)

Comment: @Heath I was of your opinion but read the standard very carefully and explained what it says in my comment above. If that idea is wrong as you say, then the standard is wrong, because it says exactly that in 6.5.2.1 As for "dumbing it down", that smacks of ad hominem.

Comment: @Jim - The standard is not wrong, but I'll reply to your comment twice.  See above where I have asked you a (rhetorical) question.

Comment: From Annex J, under Undefined Behavior: "An array subscript is out of range, *even if an object is apparently accessible* with the given subscript (as in the lvalue expression `a[1][7]` given the declaration int `a[4][5]`) (6.5.6)." Top of page 495 in n1256, emphasis mine. For an expression like `a[x][y]`, you cannot guarantee that `a` always refers to a contiguous block of memory; it can be an array of pointers pointing to non-contiguous memory.