# g++ warning on declaring multidimensional, double array

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, g++

In my C++ program I am trying to initialize a 3*3*3 array of type double with all 0's. 
In the class header file, I declared a member

```
double list[3][3][3];
```

When I printed out the content of this array, I found that not all entries are 0 as I expected. e.g. list[1][1][1] has value 4.03158e-321

Hence I manually initialized this array to all 0's in the constructor:

```
list = {{{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0}},
      {{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0}},
      {{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0}}};
```

This makes my program work, however, I got the compiler warning:

```
warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x
```

My question is therefore

1. **Why does list have non-zero entries after being initialized in the
   header?**
2. **Why do I get the above warning message, and how to get rid of it?**

My compiler is g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4) 4.5.2, with gcc version 4.5.2 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Am I missing something or can you not just do

```
class Class {
public:
    double array[3][3][3];

    Class() : array() { }
};
```

Comment: @Benjamin how about that, still missing something?

Comment: Similar to David's approach, but using class instead of struct. It is useful nevertheless. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

In C++03 you can only use that initialization when defining the array:

```
double list[3][3][3] = {{{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0}},
                        {{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0}},
                        {{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0}}};
```

The compiler is warning that according to the current standard it should not accept your code, even if it is able to process it by applying the upcoming standard rules, where the `{...}` is  called an *external-initializer*.

In this particular case, where the array is a member and you want to initialize it to all zeroes, you can just use *value-initialization* in C++0x:

```
struct test { 
   double list[3][3][3];
   test() : list()
   {}
};
```

For members of POD types (which an array of `double` is), the syntax above (`list()`) in the initializer list means that the member is to be *value-initialized* which effectively means that all values will be set to 0

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. Great explanation.

Answer (score 2):

1. In the header it's not initialized, it's just declared. Builtin types (and more in general PODs) are not automatically zero-initialized if they aren't globals (actually, that have *static storage duration*) for performance reasons (as many things in C++, initialization is an opt-in, you pay for it only if you need it).
2. That syntax is valid only when initializing an array, while that instruction is an *assignment*. That syntax, instead can be used in many more places in the new C++ standard (formerly C++0x, now C++11 since it has just been approved).

In my opinion, the quickest way to solve your problem is just to do:

```
double * firstElem=&list[0][0][0];
std::fill(firstElem, firstElem+27, 0.);
```

that treats `list` as a monodimensional array of 27 `double`s and fills it with zeroes (more info about that trick [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c/4810676#4810676)).

Notice that this argument is also treated briefly into the [array FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c/4984228#4984228).

Comment: -1. Its wrong. You cannot use `std::fill` like this, to initialize 3D array.

Comment: @Nawaz: when posting the answer I forgot the cast, now I added it.

Comment: Even this its wrong. In fact, it is more dangerous now, as you will get any warning now. Its undefined-behaviour.

Comment: @Nawaz: that usage is straight from the FAQ from FredOverflow, I'm quite sure he did the research in the standard. Still, I'll have a quick look to make sure.

Comment: @Nawaz: Actually, it's not a simple cast, I remembered wrong, there's more in it (although I'm not sure it makes any difference). Now it should be ok.

Comment: FredOverflow didn't talk about 2D array and treating it like 1D array.

Comment: @Nawaz: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c/4984228#4984228, the code block after the big grid; it should follow right from [dcl.array] ¶6-9.

Comment: @Matteo, although I prefer the current final code (`&list[0][0][0]`), I don't think that the previous one was UB. It is more *obscure* and fragile (forcing the cast means that if anything changes you are screwed), but the standard guarantees that `list` will decay to a pointer to the first element (type `double[3][3]`), and the cast will force that to be interpreted to a pointer to `double`, but the standard ensures that `(void*)&list == (void*)&list[0] == (void*)&list[0][0] == (void*)&list[0][0][0]`, so the net result is the same (just in a much better way)

Comment: @David: I too thought that it wouldn't matter, still I changed it after re-looking at the FredOverflow FAQ, because I'm sure he did the research and I didn't want to spend half an hour rambling through the standard. :)

Comment: @David: Because its treating 3D array as 1D array, that means, `&firstElem[0] == &list[0][0][0]; &firstElem[1] == &list[0][0][1]; &firstElem[2] == &list[0][0][2]` but as far as I know, the Standard nowhere guarantees that `&firstElem[3] == &list[0][1][0]`. Also, see this topic : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036104/validity-of-the-code

Comment: @Nawaz: The standard guarantees that the contents of the array are in contiguous memory. It guarantees that `&list[1]` is right after `&list[0]` in memory, so yes, it does guarantee that: `(&list[0][0][0] + 4) == &list[0][1][0]` Note that they **are** all subobjects of the same object `list`.

Answer (score 1):

There's a simpler way to do it. The following should work in C or C++, just for initializing the variable (i.e. not in an assignment):

```
double list[3][3][3] = {0};
```

The {0} is a special initializer that sets pretty much any structure to all zeroes.

Comment: Just to clarify a bit, the above declaration means "Set the first element to 0. Oh, and since I didn't specify them, set all the rest to zeroes also". I suppose you could use = {1} to set list[0][0][0] to 1, and make the rest zero, but it's not the clearest way to do that. :)

Comment: I guess it would work in the main(), but I couldn't use it in the header. i.e. I would got this error:   
a brace-enclosed initializer is not allowed here before ‘{’ token

Comment: yeah, it only works where you can do an initialization. possibly static double list... would work. However, if you're doing C++, you should consider wrapping things in a class instead. Globally-scoped non-class data is just asking for trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Why not set the values to zero with `memset` or loop ?